# Conversion of Binary number from ASCII to Decimal

Tags: c, binary, decimal

Case A: 
Decimal value 2 from [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#mediaviewer/File:ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.jpg) is represented in bits as 0100110 
converting binary number 0100110 gives decimal value 38

Case B:
Converting decimal value 2 to binary number gives 10
Converting binary number 10 gives decimal value 2

Can someone please explain 
i. Why Case A returns 38 and not 2
ii.The context of using Case A and B

Comment: Here, [have a *full* ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one shot:

The "decimal value 2" from the ASCII table is not the decimal value 2. It represents the character '2', i.e the character that we use to represent the number 2, or the decimal value 2. The ASCII table is just a convention for representing standard printable characters, and it so hapens that the character '2' sits at cell number 38

That answers your A.

Case A is used, for example, to print numerical information.

Case B is used in binary calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII code represents a standard character value, ASCII also needs to represent A-Z, symbols etc.
So the ASCII for 2 (as a character is 38).
This 2 is non numerical and simply represents a symbol humans identify as 2.

An actual numerical value of 2 only needs 2 bits, where ASCII requires many for the range of symbols it represents.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right in your question although there are a few problems with it.

- First, you have the parts of the number mixed up. 0110010 is the actual binary number.
- The decimal value of that is 50

I'm not sure what you don't understand, but I suspect you don't understand what ASCII is. It is a code that allows us to represent characters with numbers. The character for the number 2 in ASCII is not the actual number 2. That would have been handy, but it's not how it was done.